# Replacing text in a file with csv file

Tags: python, csv

I want to replace text in a text file with names that are in a csv file. For example, I have a text file that says:

```
Dear [name here],
Hello . . .. etc etc
```

And a csv file that has a 2 columns with the first name in the first and the last name in the second:

```
Joe Smith
Rachel Cool
```

How would I be able to read in the CSV file, and replace each name with the text [name here] in the file? I have this so far after opening the text and csv file and putting the first and last names in the variable names:

```
for row in f.readlines():
    names = row.split(",")[0], row.split(",")[1]
```

And after that I tried doing something like this, but it isnt working:

```
for row in textfile.readlines():
   print row.replace("[name here]", names)
```

And after running it, a TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer error. Assuming because the variable names isnt defined in the second for loop.

But how would I be able to read both files and replace just the [name here] in the text file?

Comment: And why do you want to do this using Python? It looks like a perfect example of Microsoft's Excel and Word Mail Merge.

Comment: @deads, welcome to SO. If you're happy with an answer, you may accept it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow/86979#86979

Answer (score 1):

#### Answering your question

From this line,

```
names = row.split(",")[0], row.split(",")[1]
```

`names` is a tuple of two string. But then, in this line

```
row.replace("[name here]", names)
```

you're trying to use it as a single string.

If you want to write both first/family names, you can append them as suggested in another answer, but why split them in the first place ? You may just read them in the first loop without splitting (which also solves cases where the person a three names (like Herbert George Wells)):

```
names = row
```

in the first loop, then

```
row.replace("[name here]", names)
```

in the second loop.

If you split the names because you want to use them separately, then it is unclear to me what you want to achieve.

#### Please include tracebacks in questions

The hint here is in the traceback:

```
TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer error
```

`replace` expects a string or something that acts like a string. You're feeding it a tuple. Generally, when asking a question here, it is good practice to copy the full traceback so that we know where the error occurs exactly.

#### Next issue

Now, you're going to face another issue: in the loop, you erase `names` at each iteration.

You should use a list to store all names:

```
i = 0
for row in f.readlines():
    names[i] = row
    i += 1

i = 0
for row in textfile.readlines():
    print(row.replace("[name here]", names[i]))
    i += 1
```

(Or maybe you did this correctly in your code but you stripped it away when generating a simplified example for your question.)

Answer (score 0):

The `replace()` method is expecting a string for the second parameter and you've passed it an array, hence the TypeError.

You can take the two names in the `names` array and append them together with a space in the middle using the `join` method.  Try this:

```
print row.replace("[name here]", ' '.join(names))
```